# The Python and install mysqlConnector

Tags: python, mysql, decode, encode, connector

I have the sort of uncomfortable troubles...

I want to install mysqlconnector.
So, i took it from Oracle(msi) and install it.

I opened a PyCharm, and console after all.
There I wrote for check the connection:

```
import mysql.connector
mysql.connector.connect(host='localhost',database='mysql',user='root',password='')
```

Syntax was a lighted

And there i had a trouble in console:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/���������/PycharmProjects/prime_number/mys.py", line 2, in <module>
    mysql.connector.connect(host='localhost',database='mysql',user='root',password='')
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\__init__.py", line 162, in connect
    return MySQLConnection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\connection.py", line 129, in __init__
    self.connect(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\connection.py", line 454, in connect
    self._open_connection()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\connection.py", line 417, in _open_connection
    self._socket.open_connection()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\network.py", line 472, in open_connection
    errno=2003, values=(self.get_address(), _strioerror(err)))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\errors.py", line 182, in __init__
    self.msg = self.msg % values
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xcf in position 6: ordinal not in range(128)
```

In cmd the same...
As I understand a bit - problem in coding(utf-8 or some similar)
What kind of solution i have to do ?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

When trying to connect to a non-existent mysql server, I will get the exact same traceback, except for the last trace I will get an error message:

```
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mysql/connector/network.py", line 386, in open_connection
    errno=2003, values=(self.get_address(), _strioerror(err)))
mysql.connector.errors.InterfaceError: 2003: Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost:3306' (111 Connection refused)
```

When changing the locale settings for Python, the last part `(111 Connection refused)` will get translated to the language I select.

I suspect you are from Korea (because korean UTF-8 chars are starting with 0xcf) and your Python is automatically setting the locale to korean. And then the function `_strioerror(err)` in `network.py` is crashing. This would be a bug in the mysql.connector package.

As a workaround it should work, that you change your Python locale settings to `'C'`, the default. To change the locale setting for your script, change it like this:

```
import mysql.connector
import locale
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'C')
mysql.connector.connect(host='localhost',database='mysql',user='root',password='')
```

Your program won't work after that, but you will get an error message (in english) that hopefully will help you to identify the problem.

Comment: Apparently this locale still can't decode properly: `UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xf3 in position 16: ordinal not in range(128)`